# Scatter plot with custom, individual colours from csv

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph a scatter plot where each point belongs to a group, and where each group have a colour. Unfortunately, the colours aren't displayed properly with the code I'm using:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv(text="Name,Group,Cat,Bet,InD,OutD,Close,Color
a,ANC,1,0.0465824668474985,13,15,0.5128205128205128,#ABA6A4
b,WF,1,0.006805116033755275,31,11,0.625,#BAC761
c,YC,2,0.016471518987341775,10,12,0.5263157894736842,#779BC0
d,TH,2,0.004483122362869198,10,3,0.5333333333333333,#8AB4A2
e,FL,3,0.13609064195298373,15,21,0.5882352941176471,#803C72
f,MJ,2,0.000959915611814346,2,7,0.48484848484848486,#A94D6F
g,AFPA,1,0.0057674050632911394,15,12,0.5517241379310345,#6D482E
h,PC,4,0.04844409282700422,15,24,0.5970149253731343,#80A65D
i,PC,4,0.014266877637130802,3,7,0.5063291139240507,#80A65D
", check.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

ggplot(df, aes(InD, OutD)) +
geom_point(aes(color=factor(Group), size = 5)) +
scale_colour_manual(values= levels(df$Color))
```

[image]

I'm obviously doing something wrong... What's the propper way to use custom individual colours in a scatter plot?

Comment: `levels` will always return a lexically sorted vector of unique values. Just convert the column to a character and use the column itself as values.

Comment: ...actually, this is probably more on point: `values = setNames(as.character(df$Color),df$Group)`. The reason my original suggestion didn't work is seen in the docs for `scale_color_manual`: `If unnamed, values will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with the limits of the scale.`

Comment: that works Joran, thanks a lot! Do you want to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably specifying `values` as a named vector will work better:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values= setNames(as.character(df$Color),df$Group))
```